# Implicit type compilation error although declared

Tags: scala, scalatest, json4s

Using org.json4s, I'm trying to compile this code:

```
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultJsonFormats
for {
  parsed <- Try(parse(message)).toOption
  purchase <- parsed.extractOpt[Item]
} yield {
  val datetime = new DateTime(purchase.time)
  val roundedTime = datetime.withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0)
  Key(purchase.item_id, roundedTime) -> purchase.amount
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> "No org.json4s.Formats found. Try to bring an instance of
>   org.json4s.Formats  in scope or use the org.json4s.DefaultFormats."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong implicit. You need to use `DefaultFormats` instead of `DefaultJsonFormats`:

```
implicit val formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats
```